# How to minimize mutex locks when iterating a list while being able to add elements from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In a worker thread, I iterate over a list of items that need updating. In the main thread, the user often calls a function to add elements to that list. I'm using a mutex to prevent the list from being modified while it's being iterated. Generally, the pseudocode looks like this:

```
// called by the client to add an element.
void AddElementToList(element)
{
    // lock mutex
    // add element to the list
    // unlock mutex
}

// this function is run by the worker thread
void WorkerThreadUpdate()
{
    // lock mutex
    // for each element in the list
    //     update the element
    //     mark the element for deletion if finished
    // for every finished element
    //     remove element from list
    // unlock mutex
}
```

The problem comes when updating the element. The element's update function can potentially take a long time, up to about one second in some cases. When this occurs, the user's next call to AddElementToList blocks, causing their application to freeze until all the element have been updated. The AddElementToList function is called often enough for this to be a very noticable problem.

So I'm looking for a better method. I want to update the elements while protecting the list but keep the user's main thread responsive. I'm sure this is pretty much multithreading 101, but I can't come up with the correct terms to find examples of what I'm looking for.

I was thinking of a solution that uses two lists, a "request" list and a "work" list.

The user calls AddElementToList which adds the element to the request list. In the worker thread, after the work list has been iterated, it goes through the request list and adds its elements to the work list for the next frame. It only locks when it actually modifies the lists.

```
// called by the client to add an element.
void AddElementToList(element)
{
    // lock mutex
    // add element to the request list
    // unlock mutex
}

// this function is run by the worker thread
void WorkerThreadUpdate()
{
    // for each element in the work list
    //     update the element
    //     mark the element for deletion if finished

    // for every finished element
    //     lock mutex
    //     remove element from work list
    //     unlock mutex

    // lock mutex
    // for every element in the request list
    //     add element to the work list
    // clear the request list
    // unlock mutex
}
```

I think this should work, but I'm not entirely sure. Is this an acceptable way? Are there better methods for handling this?

Comment: I think this is a case of the [Producer-Consumer](http://cs.gmu.edu/cne/modules/ipc/aqua/producer.html) pattern. Like you said, it's concurrency 101. If you use Boost, it might have classes to solve this more directly.

Comment: Unfortunately no, we don't use Boost at work. I'll check out that pattern.

Comment: From what I can understand, the pattern doesn't quite fit. The buffer isn't fixed size and the "producer" in my case should never sleep.

Comment: The pattern has an [unbounded buffer variant](http://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=producer%20consumer%20unbounded%20buffer&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdoursat.free.fr%2Fdocs%2FCS446_S06%2FCS446_S06_2_Processes6.pdf&ei=ls1PT8bpG4vrtgeNrPjPDQ&usg=AFQjCNGfLJki8MX7kvVDjNA_pb7LukLfTg&cad=rja). The producer sleeping or not is just an implementation detail, not part of the pattern. The link includes a specific solution for the 1 producer, 1 consumer case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan to queue up the additions should work.  Whether it's acceptable or not depends on whether it's acceptable to wait for queue additions until the thread does its next 'update' pass.

Is it even necessary to lock the list during the update?  What else is accessing this list, and when?  Can you lock the list, make a copy vector/list of the references, unlock the list and then run the update on each of the the copy refs one-by-one?

Comment: At least with the standard containers, he can't update his iterator while another thread might be inserting.

Comment: ..hence the copy - iterate the references in the copy and, one-by-one, lock, look up the ref, remove, unlock, update, lock, add, unlock.

Comment: I went with my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask these first:

- what actually is a list in your implementation? A dynamic array? A linked list? Some hash table?
  -- If it is a list, operation on one element should affect only the next, previous elements and possible the head and tail.
- how do you add elements to the list? Always at the end? Or can insertions occur somewhere in the middle?

Let's assume that:

- It is a single-or-bi-direction linked list, with additional variables pointed to its head and tail.
- You add the elements only at the end.

If that is the case, I would suggest doing it somehow similar to this:

```
void AddElementToList(element) {
    mutex_lock("push");
    list.push_back(element);
    mutex_release("push");
}

void WorkerThreadUpdate() {
    AddElementToList(specialElement);
    /*
      at this point we are guaranteed that other threads,
      which can only add to the list,
      will not affect us, because we have a "guard" between us and them
    */
    iterator del=NULL;
    iterator i=list.begin();
    for(; *i!=specialElement; ++i) {
         if (del) {
             del->remove();
             del=NULL;
         }
         i->update();
         if (some_condition)
             del=i;
    }
    //*i == specialElement now
    /*
      We are now operating on the guard, so we have to be careful.
      "specialElement" could still be the last element in the list.
    */
    mutex_lock("push");
    i->remove();
    mutex_release("push");
}
```

I am not sure if standard STL is thread-safe and if you can just use their implementation of the list. Read their specs. If not - just implement your own list container.

Comment: Actually, the container is a map.

Comment: I think that complicates things a lot. In a map, adding a single element, can change a lot of things. Also - in that case - I presume you are not adding new elements at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that another thread will try to access the element
you're updating.  If not, you can free the lock on the list before
starting the update, and reacquire it when you want to continue 
iterating (or to delete the object).  Something along the lines of:

```
void
WorkerThreadUpdate()
{
    // lock mutex
    ListType::iterator current = list.begin();
    while ( current != list.end() ) {
        ListType::value_type& obj = *current;
        //  unlock mutex
        //  do modifications...
        //  lock mutex
        if ( needsDeleting ) {
            current = list.erase( current );
        } else {
            ++ current;
        }
    }
    //  unlock mutex
}
```

The important thing is that you must hold the lock when actually
accessing the iterator (at least with any of the standard containers).

Of course, you'll want to use some sort of scoped lock, just in case.
(Although that might not be necessary; I think all of the code in the
locked region should be no-throw.)  I've not tried it, but I think you
could use `std::unique_lock` if you have C++11.

IMHO, while this works, it's not particularly elegant.  I'd probably
keep the list entirely on the worker side, and use a message queue to
pass the objects to be inserted, with the worker thread reading from the
message queue from time to time in order to get the objects to insert.

Comment: No other thread has access to the elements in the list. They only have access to the AddElementsToList method. The list is purely internal. We don't have C++11.

Comment: Are you sure that `obj` reference won't get invalidated when the container reallocates its memory? After all, references are merely immutable pointers and a container like `std::map` may invalidate all element pointers when adding a new entry (DJ says he is using map). Unless it won't?

Comment: @CygnusX1 It depends on the type of container.  I may be reading too much into `list`, but node based containers, like `std::list`, do not invalidate pointers and references on insertion (nor on erasure, provided the pointer or reference isn't to the erased element).  You're right, however, to raise the issue; it must be taken into account.  (But insertion in most containers would also invalidate the iterators, which would invalidate the entire loop.  Another reason for keeping the list in a single thread.)

Comment: I would prefer to have a list too, but OP said (in a comment to my response) that he is in fact using a map. Map may invalidate some of its elements upon insertion, because insertion may trigger some reorganization under the hood.

Comment: @CygnusX1 If it's an `std::map`, the standard does not allow insertion to invalidate iterators, pointers or references to existing elements.  (In practice, `std::map` is a node based container, like `std::set` and `std::list`, and node based containers never invalidate except for erasure of the designated element.)

Comment: Ah, indeed... you are right! I thought it works in a slightly different way, I don't know why....